# Can I create a child theme from a premium theme without losing my posts and page etc that I already have?

Tags: themes, child-theme, automatic-updates

I have a Wordpress installation with the theme premium, in case I created a custom page to be used, however as this site was already in production I ended up following it that way, even though I know it is not the correct one.

My question is, in case if I create a child theme I could have problems losing what I already have at the moment I say like posts, pages etc ...

Or if I create a child theme and activate it, I will continue with my website working as it is and I can add new custom pages without any problems and continue from there ...

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Your content is stored in the database, not in the theme. If you switch themes or use a child theme, the content is still there.

Also, if you run a child theme, the parent theme is still in use: Any modifications from it that you don't overwrite are still executed.

Answer (score 0):

If you create and activate a child theme you will not lose any pages or posts.

BUT, depending on your theme and how its setup, if the theme uses custom theme options, you may need to re-enter those in your child theme.

For example, settings inside of the Appearance > Customize will not carry over to your child theme.

If the site is already in production it would be best to setup a staging or test environment so you can create and test out your child theme before activating it on production.